# How to add a div after every 5 rows of data?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to add div after a group of 5 rows of data inside Listview.

I came up with using Mod 5 = 0 but I realized the last row is missing if total row count can't divided by 5.

For example, I have 11 rows of data. 
"Div" will be added after 5 and 10.

I also need to add "Div" after 11 as well. (div will display details of each group)

So, something like this

1|2|3|4|5

DIV1

6|7|8|9|10

DIV2

11|

**Div3(missing)**

Here is inline code I have so far

```
 <%# IIf((Container.DisplayIndex + 6) Mod 5 = 0, "<div id='temp" + Math.Floor((Container.DisplayIndex + 6) / 5).ToString + "' style='display:none'></div>", "")%>
```

How do I add the last div when total # can't be divided by 5?

I have to get the total# of display index somehow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare it with the ListView.Items.Count property.

This should work:

```
Dim addDiv = (Container.DisplayIndex Mod 5 = 0) OrElse _
             (Container.DisplayIndex + 1 = ListView1.Items.Count)
```

If you are using paging you should use [DataItemIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewdataitem.dataitemindex.aspx) instead of [DisplayIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewdataitem.displayindex.aspx).

**Edit**: (according to your last comment)

If you need to show the total record count you have to cast the [ListView's DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource.aspx) to it's correct type(f.e. a DataTable).

```
Dim tbl as DataTable = DirectCast(ListView1.DataSource, DataTable)
Dim totalCount as Int32 = tbl.Rows.Count
```

or in one line:

```
DirectCast(ListView1.DataSource, DataTable).Rows.Count
```

But this works only on databinding and not on every postback because the DataSource will be disposed at the end of the Page-Lifecycle.

Comment: wow, stackoverflow is the best site I've ever used... super quick dead on answers... Anyway I did end up using Container.DisplayIndex +1 = ListView1.Items.Count and it worked!! However another issue came up. What if I have 31 rows of data? the page displays only 20 data so display index and total data will not match in 2nd page... anyway your answer was super! I just got another issue that I didn't expect.

Comment: @shinya: sorry for the late answer, i was sleeping ;) Edited my answer according to your comment.

Comment: I had to come back to this issue again. So I used DataItemIndex but I also need to know the total RowCount somehow.ListView1.Items.Count is always the page size (in my case 20). How do I reference TotalRowCount using inline code?

Answer (score 1):

the "+6" makes it look like you're guessing around how the modulo function works :)

try this:

`<%# IIf(Container.DisplayIndex Mod 5 = 4 Or Container.DisplayIndex = ListView.Items.Count  , "<div id='temp" + (1+Math.Floor(Container.DisplayIndex/5)).ToString + "' style='display:none'></div>", "")%>`

so first (index+6)%5 == 0 is the same as index%5 == 4,

second floor((index+6)/5) results in 2 when index=4, this is not what you want. 
using 1+floor(index/5) will give you the correct results --- you could even drop the "1+" if you want the index to start from 0.

(p.s. i don't know asp.net, sorry if there's compiler errors)

Comment: Is 4 % 5 = 4 ?? 4 divided by 5 's remainder is not 4. is it? Yes this is first time to use Module. :-)

Comment: yes it is :) 
when you think about modulo just think about calculating with seconds in a minute. e.g. 61%60 = 1, but also 1%60 = 1, and of course also 121%60 = 1.

Comment: p.s. you can play with this some more in wolfram alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%280...20%29+mod+5